# Vaadin 8: Grid cell tooltip example

Tags: grid, tooltip, vaadin8

I would like to have tooltips in a Vaadin 8 grid cell. I think this can be implemented with setDescriptionGenerator. I tried to use it as

```
grid.addColumn(Property::getStringValue).setDescriptionGenerator(Property::getDescription);
```

But this does not do anything. I am looking for a code example to implement tooltips in Vaadin 8 grid.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: That should be it. I've tested it with the current 8.1.5 and it works just as advertised. Could you please describe what you were expecting and what is happening, or even better, add a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to illustrate your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It really works like this. Now I could see the tooltip popup when I got with the mouse into the grid cell. I wonder why I did not see it when I tried it the first time. Thanks this solved the problem.

Comment: A missing `CTRL` + `S` maybe?! :-)